# Should Managed Service Identities be used for Azure App Service access from Console App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a console app that is running inside our enterprise that needs to access as App Service Web API.  What is the best way to handle authentication.  I tried registering the App with AD, but it still seems like it cant't see the App Service.  I tried the following code, but I am not sure this is even the right API to use.

```
var App = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(CoreConstants.Auth_ClientId)
.WithAuthority(CoreConstants.Auth_Authority)
                .WithClientSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .Build();

var token =  App.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
token.Wait();
```

This fails saying the scope is not defined. It looks like it is in Azure.

Comment: Do you create the role assignment for managed service identity of your App service?

Comment: Yes I did create the role assignment.   But is this even the right approach/API?

Comment: It seems not right. See [Obtaining tokens for Azure resources with App MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create role assignments for your App identity. And then you can get the access tokens from the identity. The code will like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
// ...
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net");
// OR
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
```

Do not forget to add references to the [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) and any other necessary NuGet packages to your application. For more details, see  [Obtaining tokens for Azure resources with App MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work.  I am sure I do not have something set up correctly.  Where should I be creating role assignments on the App Identity?  Does that have to be done via the manifest?

Comment: @DanBlake You can create the role assignment in the Azure portal or using Azure CLI or Azure Powershell. Take a look at the [role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

Comment: Unfortunatlly this did not resolve the issue.  Had to just build the request in http myself to the auth2/token endpoint